# vxworks 7 SDK start container by script

Tags: containers, real-time, vxworks, oci-container

I am using the free available vxworks 7 and am trying to measure the time it takes for the real time container to run. My idea would be to measure the time, start the container and then measure the time when the Container is stopped. But how do I start the container with a script?

I found the "extern STATUS vxcStart()" function in the containers programming guide, but cannot compile it because the function vxcStart is undefined. I guess I need a header-file for this but dont know which.

If you have other ideas on how to test the real time functionalities of the containers, let me know.

Any help is highly appreciated :)